# How to retrieve firefox passwords

Tags: firefox, passwords

I was using Firefox in Windows but then I switched to Linux where I also use firefox. I forgot to export my passwords. I can't start Windows anymore but I still have access to the Windows partition from Linux. Can I retrieve my firefox passwords from the Windows partition and use them in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I installed a portable copy of Firefox in Windows running in a virtual machine. Then I copied over the whole profile folder into it. When I started Firefox, I was able to access my passwords and export them.

Comment: you ran the portable version and it didnot automatically replace the previous/existing profile folder.. PLEASE

Comment: The portable version had its own profile folder. I just copied the contents of the old profile folder into it. Try it, it works.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows it's located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXX
You'll want to copy over the keyX.txt and signonsX.db files.

Comment: I found key3.db and signons.sqlite and copied them over. However, no passwords were imported.